# pop up select list for android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get away from using 5 buttons when I would like to have one when pressed pops up a window that allows the user to select where they want to go.

Example: button "Country"

```
 <Button
android:id="@+id/countrySelect"
android:layout_width="300px"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/backhome"
android:layout_x="8px"
android:layout_y="21px"
>
</Button>
```

and when pressed it would pop up a list of countrys to select from: Something like-

```
countrySelect.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {         
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){

           //POP UP SELECT MENU WHEN SELECTED START A NEW INTENT
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ***SELECT MENU CONTROLS***.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }

 });
```

Sorry this probably is easy fix but I am not having much luck when I researched it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add **spinner** in your layout.xml :

```
<Spinner 
android:id="@+id/areaspinner"
android:layout_width="150dip"
android:layout_height="40dip"
android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
android:padding="5dip"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"/>
```

Now in Activity.java :

```
areaspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaspinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, array);  //array you are populating  
    adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    areaspinner.setAdapter(adapter2);
        areaspinner.setSelection(Integer.parseInt(strarea));
```

Now you can get gtghe selected value from the spinner by :

```
int ipos=areaspinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
String str=array[iPos];
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

You could use `AlertDialog` for that. It can show a list of items and react when user taps on any of them http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the documentation.

Comment: Excellent link. Contains lots of useful examples. +1.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use Spinner or Single choice alert dialog for the same.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a popup menu like a spinner but with a button, you can use [PopupMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)

see [this](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/working-with-androids-popupmenu-class/#) example